# DASK dataframe.to_csv storing files on worker instead of locally

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm quite new to DASK, I'm trying to set up a distributed cluster on a private cloud. Right now I have the scheduler and one worker, both running in the same Docker container, on the same machine. They're started with `dask-scheduler` and `dask-worker tcp://localhost:8786` respectively.

I'm connecting from my local machine to the scheduler. For the sake of simplicity, let's say that I'm running an IPython console locally, in a directory `/home/my_user/local_directory`. I'm running:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client('scheduler_host:scheduler_port')
```

This works fine. I can do some operations, schedule work, `.compute()` on `dataframes` also works as expected.

I'm having an issue when saving results to a file. When following the example from [here](https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/01-data-access.html#Create-artificial-dataset) and running:

```
import dask
import os
if not os.path.exists('data'):
    os.mkdir('data')
df = dask.datasets.timeseries()
df.to_csv('data/*.csv')
```

I'd expect that the csv files (1..30.csv) will be created in a local `data` directory, i.e. in `/home/my_user/local_directory/data` on my local machine. Instead, the files are saved on the scheduler/worker machine in a `/home/my_user/local_directory/data` directory. The same happens when replacing the last line with `df.to_csv('data/test.csv', single_file=True)`.

Something more interesting happens when replacing that line with `df.to_parquet('test.parquet')`. In the `parquet` case, an empty `test.parquet` directory is created on my local machine and the results are stored in `/home/my_user/local_directory/test.parquet` on the scheduler/worker. It will also raise errors if the directory is not accessible locally.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59423474/10243384), running `to_parquet` should save the files locally. But according [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377801/write-output-directly-from-a-dask-worker#comment97483409_55378534), the files are created locally on the worker machine. If the second is true, why would the parquet directory be created locally? Why would the worker use my local path when storing the data?

Is this how it should be working? Perhaps I'm doing something wrong with the setup? Please advise! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dask dataframe storage functions save results from the workers.  Typically people use Dask with a global file system, like NFS, HDFS, or a cloud object store.

If you want to store things locally then you should either use Dask on a single machine, or if your results are small you can call `.compute` to bring the results back to your local machine as a pandas dataframe, and then use the Pandas storage functions.